# Восстановление пароля

Tags: php

Как принципиально работает система восстановления пароля? Меня интересует метод, где отправляется ссылка на почту, и пользователь перейдя по ссылке меняет сам себе пароль. Где и как хранить, чтобы было максимально защищеннее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рядом с ячейкой, в которой хранится пароль, создается ячейка со статусом и временем.
1) если кто-то нажал на ссылку "восстановить пароль", юзеру улетает письмо, содержащее хэш айдишника.
2) юзер прошел по ссылке. 1) если уложился в установленное время - даем возможность сменить пароль, устанавливая время сессии пару минут. 2) если не успел - убираем статус смены пароля.

Comment: Вопрос, поля статус и время должны быть в той же ьаблице, где и все данные пользователя?

Comment: не обязательно. Но я бы сделал в той же, где пароль и логин(почта итп. Т.е. то, что у каждого пользователя должно быть обязательно). А остальные данные пользователя(необязательные) - в другой. Это облегчит поиск.

Comment: однако... О_о

Comment: Что такое?

Comment: Удивлен, что этот ответ принят. =) Но приятно удивлен.

Comment: Оправдали мои предположения. Идея понравилась.

Answer (score 2):

Рядом с полем пароля в поле восстановления, например, прописываете код, с которым человек должен прийти. В ссылке передавать мыло и этот код. Или логин и код или ИД и код (чтобы можно было четко указать кому именно восстанавливать пароль). Далее проверка совпадения и смена пароля на рандомный, и отсылка его на мыло, и очистка кода восстановления. При пустом коде отсылать с восстановлением подальше.

Comment: Я требование перечитайте, пожалуйста. Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь сам сменил пароль перейдя по ссылке восстановления.

Comment: ну и в чем проблема? при совпадении выведите ему два поля - пароль+подтверждение и в скрытые поля код восстановления + ид или логин и вперед

Answer (score 2):

Храните в базе пару пользователь - ключ - expiration. Когда пользователь проходит по ссылке сверяете все данные и если всё ок, то даёте менять пароль. Если нет, то посылаете нафиг.

Comment: Блин, опоздал на двадцать секунд :)

Comment: А я думал, я опоздаю, ибо писал как диссертацию. ))

Comment: А я на минуту. И что? =) Зато убедился, что мыслю более-менее правильно.